# Docker compose django, nginx, daphne expose internet in EC2

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

Hello i need expose the containers to internet i read thats is with ip table and works in in the instance but i can't access by internet for the moment and this is my configuration:

EC2 instance:
Ubuntu

Docker vserions:
Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350
docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    command: redis-server --port 6379
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    environment:
      - REDIS_MODE="LRU"
      - REDIS_MAXMEMORY="800mb"


  server:
    build: .
    command: daphne rubrica.asgi:application --port 8000 --websocket_timeout -1 --bind 0.0.0.0 -v2

    volumes:
      - .:/src
      - ${AWS_CREDENTIALS_PATH}:/root/.aws/
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/
    links:
      - server
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - server
    command: ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

networks:
  docker-network:
    driver: networktest
```

network

```
sudo docker create --name networktest --network <instance ip> --publish 8080:80 --publish 443:443  nginx:latest
```

and this is the rules in my instance

[image]

If someone can help me to know what i need or a can't see in the configuration.

Comment: Not really possible to answer this without knowing if your EC2 instance has a public IP and its firewall/VPC settings allow inbound traffic... And that has nothing to do with Docker, but rather how server ports are bound on the instance itself

Comment: @OneCricketeer  i update the ask with the input rules

Comment: First, never open port 22 SSH to the public internet... 1) What are you trying to connect to? Nginx or something else? If only Nginx, you only need ports 80+443 2) Your `network create` command uses port 8080, but the Compose file uses port 80. Compose creates a network, by default, so you shouldn't need this for a simply port mapping 3) Do the ports actually get bound on the host? If you SSH to the instance, can you `curl localhost`, for example, and it returns something?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  first i only need mount a server test for a proyect with docker  when i run `curl localhost` i get this `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: Sounds like the nginx container isn't running, then